# Query the value of the four neighbors of an element in a numpy 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D array of 5*5 like this:

```
>>> np.random.seed(100)
>>> a = np.random.randint(0,100, (5,5))
>>> a
array([[ 8, 24, 67, 87, 79],
       [48, 10, 94, 52, 98],
       [53, 66, 98, 14, 34],
       [24, 15, 60, 58, 16],
       [ 9, 93, 86,  2, 27]])
```

if I have an initial position, is there any way to quickly and easily get the values of its four neighbors around it? The method I'm using now is a bit cumbersome:

Suppose the current position is [x, y] (if x=2, y=3 then the value in the array is 14,)，then the position above it is [x-1, y], the bottom is [x+1, y], the left side is [y-1, x], and the right side is [y+1, x]. I use the following four lines of code to get the values of neighbors.

```
curr_val = a[2,3]
up_val = a[2+1, 3]
bott_val = a[2-1, 3]
left_val = a[2, 3+1]
right_val = a[2, 3-1]
```

So my question is is there a more convenient function in numpy that can do this and even query the values of four neighbors at once?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to write your current method ?

Comment: Ok, I'll make it up right away. Actually, it's just four sentences.

Comment: What if the initial position is in the corner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use:

```
mask = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                 [1, 0, 1],
                 [0, 1, 0]]).astype(bool)
a[i-1:i+2, j-1:j+2][mask]
```

output:

```
array([53, 93, 94, 86])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the shortest method, but a flexible way could be to use a mask and a convolution to build this mask.

The advantage is that you can use any mask easily, just change the kernel.

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

kernel = [[0,1,0],  # define points to pick around the target
          [1,0,1],
          [0,1,0]]
mask = np.zeros_like(a, dtype=bool) # build empty mask
mask[x,y] = True                    # set target(s)

# boolean indexing
a[convolve2d(mask, kernel, mode='same').astype(bool)]
```

output: `array([52, 98, 34, 58])`

Comment: It's not the shortest, but it's a very clever way.

Comment: Thanks @skywave1980, I like convolutions a lot, very handy tool (NB. you can wrap everything in a function to make it easy to use) ;)

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is this one taking usec to compute. Some times shortest is not the best. This one is very simple to understand and has no package dependencies.

This also works for edge-cases.

```
def neighbors(matrix: np.ndarray, x: int, y: int):
    x_len, y_len = np.array(matrix.shape) - 1
    nbr = []
    if x > x_len or y > y_len:
        return nbr
    if x != 0:
        nbr.append(matrix[x-1][y])
    if y != 0:
        nbr.append(matrix[x][y-1])
    if x != x_len:
        nbr.append(matrix[x+1][y])
    if y != y_len:
        nbr.append(matrix[x][y+1])
    return nbr
```

Comment: It seems that numpy does not have a similar function, this custom function is really convenient.

Comment: @skywave1980 Keep in mind that your accepted answer does not work for edge cases.

Comment: Thank you, I understand that I only intend to process data in the middle of the grid.

Comment: Should 'x_len, y_len = matrix.shape' be 'x_len, y_len = np.array(a.shape) - 1'? To avoided not working on boundaries?

Comment: You are correct. I assumed that you would do the boundary check before calling the function, I am updating the answer to return an empty list on that case.

Comment: @ Kyriakos Psarakis Thanks for your update, it's also a very good answer.

Comment: can we have it in all  8 directions instead of 4 ?